# flickcurl error - Method flickr.oauth.access_token failed

Tags: c++, oauth, flickr

I have a problem with authentication in Flickr using OAuth protocol and flickcurl library.
I'm stuck in "Create access token" step. I have correct oauth_client_key, oauth_client_secret, created request_token, request_token_secret, authorize_uri and Verifier set (as described [here](http://librdf.org/flickcurl/api/flickcurl-auth-authenticate.html)), but `flickcurl_oauth_create_access_token(...)` function returns error, and generate message:

> flickcurl error - Method flickr.oauth.access_token failed with error 0 (null) (HTTP 401)

My application:

```
#include <flickcurl.h>
#include "ConfigFile.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    flickcurl_init();
    flickcurl *fc = flickcurl_new();

    ConfigFile cf(".flickcurl.conf");

    string oauth_client_key = cf.getValueOfKey("oauth_client_key");
    string oauth_client_secret = cf.getValueOfKey("oauth_client_secret");

    flickcurl_set_oauth_client_key(fc, oauth_client_key.c_str());
    flickcurl_set_oauth_client_secret(fc, oauth_client_secret.c_str());

    string oauth_token = cf.getValueOfKey("oauth_token");
    string oauth_token_secret = cf.getValueOfKey("oauth_token_secret");
    if (oauth_token.empty() || oauth_token_secret.empty())
    {
        if (flickcurl_oauth_create_request_token(fc, NULL))
            return 1;
        string request_token = flickcurl_get_oauth_request_token(fc);
        string request_token_secret = flickcurl_get_oauth_request_token_secret(fc);
        string uri = flickcurl_oauth_get_authorize_uri(fc);

        cout << "Application wants to link to your Flickr account. \n"
                "To authorize it go to: "<< uri << endl;
        cout << "Type in Verifier displayed on a page: ";
        string verifier;
        cin >> verifier;

        flickcurl_set_oauth_request_token(fc, request_token.c_str());
        flickcurl_set_oauth_request_token_secret(fc, request_token_secret.c_str());

        if (flickcurl_oauth_create_access_token(fc, verifier.c_str()))
            return 1;
        oauth_token = flickcurl_get_oauth_token(fc);
        oauth_token_secret = flickcurl_get_oauth_token_secret(fc);
    }
    flickcurl_set_oauth_token(fc, oauth_token.c_str());
    flickcurl_set_oauth_token_secret(fc, oauth_token_secret.c_str());

    flickcurl_free(fc);
    flickcurl_finish();

    return 0;
}
```

*ConfigFile is just a simple configuration file parser. oauth_token and oauth_token_secret have to be created(through flickcurl_oauth_create_access_token() call) if it is not found in configuration file.
What is missed or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of flickcurl you are using but there were a bunch of bugs fixed in the last release 1.24 and some more in tbe upcoming 1.25.  OAuth is tricky to get right.

More specifically this commit in 1.24 might fix it: https://github.com/dajobe/flickcurl/commit/726c6737d7494f688a22f7a581bcadb61cf018d0